# Response Time of sleeping gwan server script

Tags: timeout, execution, g-wan

I want to figure out how gwan responds if a script takes longer than 1 second to finish.

To do so, I used the `sleep()` function in the `hello.c` example:

```
#include "gwan.h"  
#include <unistd.h>  

int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{  
    sleep(5);
    static char msg[] = "Hello, ANSI C!";  
    xbuf_ncat(get_reply(argv), msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);  
    return 200; // return an HTTP code (200:'OK')
}
```

The response time I got from Chrome was >= 5 seconds, as expected.

Then, I have run a Weighttp concurrency test, and here is the response time I got from Chrome in ms (millisecond).
Is this a caching issue? Where the 5 second sleep time has gone?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you refresh in chrome while the test is running? If yes then I think you are hitting the micro-cache. That will explain why the response is in ms. http://gwan.ch/faq#cache

Comment: @RichardHeath after the test has finished.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sleep(5);` test is pointless (at best) and, as expected, G-WAN **timeouts the blocking script** to *avoid blocking* the server because of a buggy script.

If the blocking servlet is used under concurrency, lik eyou did later, then, instead of pointlessly timing-out every execution (this would take time), G-WAN *flags* this servlet as buggy and no longer executes it.

This blocking issue would not exist with a more interesting test: see how G-WAN can serve a [10-second system PING](http://gwan.ch/source/stream3.c) *without ever blocking*.

If you have a script that needs 5 seconds to do its job then you **SHOULD NOT** wait for 5 seconds. Blocking the server thread is the least intelligent thing to do.

If you do that with another server, and say, use a single-threaded program like Nginx, this will just prevent new connections from being processed: your server will be dead.

G-WAN does better because (a) it uses several threads and (b) because it has dedicated *aynchronous* interfaces, see below.

For replies that span over a long period of time G-WAN offers:

1. a Comet API (see the [comet.c](http://gwan.ch/source/comet.c) example)
2. a streaming API (see the [stream1](http://gwan.ch/source/stream1.c)/[2](http://gwan.ch/source/stream2.c)/[3](http://gwan.ch/source/stream3.c).c examples)
3. a transparent asynchronous interface to avoid blocking I/O.

So, if you want to see how G-WAN processes *real-life* slow scripts, then write some realistic code.

Comment: forget about the test, my original question is about why the response time after the weighttp test has completed, is just ms(millisecond)?

Comment: Because the servlet has **timed-out**.